# Convert military time in varchar format to standard time

Tags: sql, database, oracle, datetime-conversion

I am working with a table that stores times in military format as varchar(6).
I need to display and calculate durations.

How can I show for example 1015 as 10:15 and calculate 1015 - 30 getting 09:45 ?

I didn't find any conversion functions yet.

Thanks in advance.

Conversion functions and to_date.

Comment: You need to add a tag what you are actually working with.

Comment: Update your column to DATE(TIME) and make your life a whole lot easier, then you can use things like DATE_SUB (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_sub.asp) and other date functions

Comment: sounds like simple string manipulation. just make sure to `% 12 + 12` the hour to convert 00 and 12 to 12am and 12pm respectively

Comment: I can't change the column definition as the data is used by a commercial application.

Comment: The string manipulation is not sufficient as I need to calculate correctly with these values.